# Kohana template controller, no auto rendering

Tags: templates, controller, kohana

I have a controller (Controller_Product) that extends Controller_Template.
In the Controller_Product I have some actions (create, edit, etc.) where I need the template to be rendered, but some actions (ex. save, delete) have to return a json object, so I don't need the template to be rendered.
How can I solve this problem?

I can set the $this->auto_render to FALSE in my *save* or *delete* action, but the template will be created in this case too, even if will be no rendered. I think this is not very elegant to load a template when I don't actually need it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```php
public function before()
{
        if (in_array($this->request->action(), array('save', 'delete')))
        {
                $this->auto_render = FALSE;
        }

        parent::before();
}
```

[edit]

A better approach might be to check for an ajax request:

```php
public function before()
{
        if ($this->request->is_ajax())
        {
                $this->auto_render = FALSE;
        }

        parent::before();
}
```

Comment: Checking for ajax request can work in most cases for me, because I post data via ajax every time.
Thanks for your suggestion.